# PostGIS Query to merge geometry polygon

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have to query PostGIS to merge the resulting geometry.
(they are all polygons).

```
select *
from da_zo
where quartiere  in ('xxx','xxx','xxxx','xxx')
```

the result is 3 rows with 3 polygon-type geometries.
I need geometry merge.

Ho provato anche a creare una view in questo modo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW circuito_1 AS 
 select *
from da_zo dz 
where quartiere  in ('xxx','xxx','xxxx','xxxx')
```

actually in QGIS if I import the view I see the merge of the geometries.
Is it a correct way?

The next step is to display only the points that are contained within the polygon.
I have a table in my database with all points.
In this case I don't know how to do it

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Your SQL doesn't attempt to merge geometries. For that you'd need ST_UnaryUnion. You don't provide an attempt to accomplish an ST_Within query, either. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on one task and include the SQL of your attempt.

Comment: Also, "Ho provato anche a creare una view in questo modo:" will need translating

Answer (score 3):

Merge is called ST_UNION in PostGIS.

But you dont need to merge them.

Inner join the polygon and point layer with a where clause:

```
select pnt.*
from public.somepolygontable as poly
join public.somepointtable as pnt
on st_intersects(poly.geom, pnt.geom)
where poly.id IN(5732, 5740, 5561)
```

[image]

Make sure both your tables have [indexes.](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html)